# Simple PHP/MySQL ORM Code Not Executing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, idiorm

I'm trying to run a simple query with an ORM that is built on top of PDO.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
$message = ORM::for_table("messages")
                    ->where("to_user_id", $user_id)
                    ->where("deleted", 0)
                    ->where("reply_id", $message_id)
                    ->where("read", 0)
                    ->order_by_desc("time")
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->count();
```

(This is using j4mie's Idiorm, https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm)

This code seems like it would work, but I get the following MySQL error:

```
Error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: 
    Syntax error or access violation: 
        1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
        check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
        right syntax to use near 'read = '0' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1' 
        at line 1' in /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/lib/classes/ORM.class.php:492 
    Stack trace: 
        #0 /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/lib/classes/ORM.class.php(492): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
        #1 /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/lib/classes/ORM.class.php(289): ORM->run() 
        #2 /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/app/models/Message.class.php(73): ORM->count() 
        #3 /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/app/views/Messages/IndexView.php(42): Message::conversation_changed('3', '4', true) 
        #4 /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/app/templates/GameTemplate.php(13): require('/Users/chromium...') 
        #5 /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/lib/classes/Load.class.php(83): require('/Users/chromium...') 
        #6 /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/app/controllers/M on line 492 of /Users/chromium/Documents/root/e119/lib/classes/ORM.class.php
```

Comment: I've not come across that one. I'd debug this by taking out a few of the where() clauses and re-adding them one at a time, or maybe by adding a few debugging statements into the ORM class code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` and `time` are [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mySQL.

You'll have to rename the columns, or wrap backticks around the columnn names:

```
 ->order_by_desc("`time`")
 ->where("`read`", 0)
```

(provided the ORM allows that, of course.)

Comment: Good call, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Renamed the collumn to "timedate" and got the same error.

Comment: @Archio `READ` is also a reserved word, try renaming that as well

Comment: That was it, thanks! Wow, two reserved words, time to check the MySQL  manual next time.